# How to reset a Keycloak authentication flow and display a message or error message?

Tags: keycloak

Within a custom authentication flow SPI, you can reset the entire flow simply returning

```
context.resetFlow();
```

in e.g. an action method.

However, can you attach a message or attribute when resetting the flow, basically passing it into the Freemarker UI upon reset?

Answer (score 1):

```
context.forkWithErrorMessage(new FormMessage('label', 'Your error message here'));
```

Comment: this resets to the login flow.
If you were on registration flow, it would take you to login after attempt